# Is there any glossary of all the plants mentioned in zeraim?

Tags: mishna

I have been trying to learn zeraim, but I keep getting stuck on all the names of the plants. Is there any comprehensive listing?

Comment: Check out Yehuda Felix's books

Comment: Lovers of classics should check out the magnum opus of [Immanuel Löw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_L%C3%B6w), the volumes of [Die Flora der Juden](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/freimann/content/titleinfo/781127). [He was one of the main influences of Yehuda Feliks.]

Comment: Not a recommendation, as I haven't actually read it, but Rav Kappah has a sefer הצומח במשנה (or some title like that).

Comment: The new editions of the Aruch on Yerushalmi have pictures

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the book [הצומח והחי במשנה](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=191843&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=1) by יהודה פליקס. I found it invaluable when learning משניות סדר זרעים. It's in Hebrew but includes, if I recall right, the taxonomic and English names of each plant, and pictures. Not everyone agrees with his identifications of the various types of plant, and, if I recall right, he doesn't always include even major dissenting opinions. It's been a while since I've opened the book, though; my memory may be misserving me.

Comment: If someone has used the book more recently than I and can edit this answer post for accuracy, please do!

Comment: The book is on אוצר החכמה. Is there anything particular you'd like to know about it? (I haven't used it; just looked for it out of curiosity.)

Comment: @Shokhet, just to make sure that my statements in the answer are correct